# Bulk Update Participant Status via REST API

Tags: rest

I am trying to find a way to bulk update participants' status via the REST api. I could only think of using the API chaining method. I tried to do a for loop to update individually but I got random number of successful updates.

Would like to know if there is a better way to do it ? I am calling from an android app using Retrofit2.

thanks,
j.

Answer (score 1):

The right place to experiment with possibilities of the API is API Explorer that you can find at *Support -> Developer - API Explorer* in your local CivCRM instance or on the [Demo site](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/api#explorer).

All the participants of an event can be selected with:

`http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Participant&action=get&api_key=userkey&key=sitekey&json={"sequential":1,"event_id":3}`

The update of status can be accomplished with the create action in combination with an already existing participant_id. For example:

`http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Participant&action=create&api_key=userkey&key=sitekey&json={"sequential":1,"id":3,"status_id":"Cancelled"}`

moves the status to Cancelled.

Success with your app.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I managed continue using the Chain API calls to make it happened. It works great.